# Is Microsoft Graph API using SMTP at the back?

Tags: microsoft-graph-api

I am trying to use Graph API to send 20 messages within 1 minute to certain teams channel. Does Graph API use SMTP protocol to send email?

```
POST /me/messages/{id}/forward
POST /users/{id | userPrincipalName}/messages/{id}/forward
POST /me/mailFolders/{id}/messages/{id}/forward
POST /users/{id | userPrincipalName}/mailFolders/{id}/messages/{id}/forward
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Microsoft Graph uses the user's Exchange Online or Outlook.com mailbox to send the mail. Those services do use SMTP.